# how to design table structure for table data searching become faster in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5, key

Main table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Timetable] (
    [location]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,   
    [term]                       NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [employeeId]                 BIGINT         NOT NULL,    
    [subjectCode]                NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL, 
    [lectureComment]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [lectureDate]                DATE           NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Timetable] 
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([location] ASC,  [term] ASC, [employeeId] ASC, [subjectCode] ASC));
```

This table has more than 400k rows

I want to take backup of all rows to another database and include  academicYear column which store data with academic Year column

TimetableBackup structure

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimetableBackup] (
    [academicYear]               NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL, 
    [location]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,   
    [term]                       NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [employeeId]                 BIGINT         NOT NULL,    
    [subjectCode]                NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL, 
    [lectureComment]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [lectureDate]                DATE           NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TimetableBackup] 
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([location] ASC,  [term] ASC, [employeeId] ASC, [subjectCode] ASC));
```

What should be the structure for **TimetableBackup** table so i can store data my making **academicYear** as master column so later table data searching become faster?

Comment: It really depends on what types of searches you are performing - searching by which columns, extracting which columns, the amount of rows returned by the given search. You may need to apply different measures for different searches but you first need to provide more details.

Comment: searching all depends on either primary key of table or academicYear.   how to store data seperated with using column academicYear

Comment: Please don't use indian words like 'lakh' here. People from other countries will not understand it.

Comment: Your table is not really a backup, but the history of time tables? So that the other table contains current data, and the other the old ones?

Answer (score 2):

In order to optimize searches by `acadamicYear` you can do the following steps:

- create a lookup table year with the following structure:

  ```
   [academicYearID] SMALLINT
  ,[acadamicYear] NVARCHAR(128)
  ```

  in your backup table, use the integer column instead
- created an index on the `academicYearID` column in your backup table - the indexes will be small (but it contains the PK storage in order to reference the original table, so size is relative here);

Having such index could optimize particular search queries when the engine decides to use  the index to locate the records and then to perform lookup to the original table.

Can you apply this logic to the original table fields?

The following columns are part of your PK:

```
[location]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL   
[term]                       NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
[employeeId]                 BIGINT         NOT NULL    
[subjectCode]                NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
```

Look of this fields as data that needs to be read by the engine. You can try to normalized your table more. You have a table where employees are stored, right? Why don't you create such tables for the locations, the terms, the subject codes? You can have as a result PK with four integers which will be really better then the current one.

Having such PK will optimize your reads operations as small data is going to be read. It will improve the other indexes size, too (from there you get small reads again and faster queries).